# Forward proxy on apache with .htaccess to jupyter notebook

Tags: .htaccess, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have Jupyter running one server and I want to froward to it from another server. I did it to django by adding .htaccess file to folder where I wanted to it go forward. Htaccess file had this in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://server.address:port/jupyter/$1 [P]
```

I tried same to Jupyter but I can't connect to it. It either gives my 404 error or goes to some loop (ploting on console 304 /?) by going no where. Any idea how forward proxy with .htaccess file to jupyteri?

EDIT:
 I got it now (almost) with adding this line to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /jupyter/
```

I can create file and open it, but I can't run any code.

Comment: You can redirect from the vhost
  `RequestHeader set Origin "http://example.ovh:9999"
  Redirect permanent / http://ipynb.example.ovh`

Comment: what is  http://ipynb.example.ovh?

Comment: `http://ipynb.example.ovh` will be the URL of your jupyter server and `http://example.ovh:9999` will be the URL of the another server from where you want to redirect to jupyter server